# CoffeeScript, Node.js, MongoDB and JasperReports, is it possible?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, jasper-reports, coffeescript

I just realized a JSF (web JavaScript application) that connect to a MongoDB database and generate a report (PDF) thanks to JasperReports Library (so with a .java file).

Is it possible to do the same thing with a web application in CoffeeScript and Node.js? I am really new to this, so I don't know where to start.

**For example**: Is it possible to run a .java thanks to Node.js or CoffeeScript?

Answer (score 6):

JSF is actually a [JavaServer Faces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Faces) application, not a JavaScript application. JavaScript (which Node.js, CoffeeScript are based on) is *not* equivalent to Java despite the similarity in names.

If you already have a JSF-based application then you already should have everything you need to create a web-based application. There is no need for Node.js, CoffeeScript, etc.

Go take a look at JSP, Tomcat, etc. to figure out how to render web pages rather than output to PDF and you should be set.

Comment: Yes but as I said I don't want to keep this JSF. I want to use coffescript, nodejs and mongoDB because i have to import this to an another web application based on these languages.

Comment: Well, first, you should be more specific about what you want to keep and what you don't.  There is a connector for MongoDB that can be used with Jasper Reports, there is a driver for node.js that can also connect to MongoDB.  As for node.js and integration with Jasper Reports, I have no idea (this is assuming that most of the work you reference has been done in Jasper Reports and you intend to keep it).  If you want to get rid of Jasper Reports too then you are either going to have to write the entire thing from scratch or find a javascript substitute.

Comment: Thanks you for this answer, i searched a lot for node.js and his integration with Jasper Reports . I didn't find anything. And if I have to get rid of Jasper Reports it will be a lot of work I guess. I know that Pentaho is also a report tool but I guess that's the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to rewrite your application in javascript and run it on node.js, you should be able to use [PDFKit](http://pdfkit.org/) to build the PDFs.

If you only wish to use your existing application and integrate it with a node.js server, I think you would be wise to run them in parallel (or proxy requests to your JSF application through node, in case that makes sense). It's hard to give a better answer unless you can state more clearly what it is you want to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for the PDFKit info, No i want to start over because I guess I can't use the java file anymore. And as there is no info for nodejs and jasperreport integration, your solution (run them in parrallel) may be an alternative

Comment: I just found this [nodejs module](https://github.com/nearinfinity/node-java) do you think it would be possible to use jasper report library with it ?

Comment: I haven't seen that module before, very interesting. That said, no, I don't think it would be a great idea. You could always try, though!

Comment: I going to try... I guess the other solution would be yours (parallel run) But anyway I would'nt know where to start. So I may need your help later :)

Comment: Now I've looked at what Jasper Reports is and it seems pretty complex. If I were you and I already had a JSF application working, I would just proxy that behind a node.js app (you haven't told us why you need to "import" it into a node.js app, but I take your word for it).

Comment: I'm here on SO answering questions, to help, to gather reputation, and to learn. I'm not offering consultation for free. That said, please state your questions clearly, write down what you want to accomplish and why, and I'm certain you will get great answers. In this particular case, I'm gathering that you have a java program, embedding Jasper Reports, talking to a MongoDB. If you want to build a web interface for that, there are several ways to go. What is unclear is exactly _how_ and _why_ you want to integrate this java program in a node.js server.

Comment: So here is my generate.java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9435559/jasperreports-library-and-mongodb And in my jsf application I click on a button and it connect to mongo, compile the report and give me the pdf file . The thing is that the enterprise already have a web framework in coffescript/nodejs, so i need to find a way to integrate my JSF to this web framework or start over. I don't have any java program (except if a JSF is a java program). So to answer your questions : How I want to integrate this JSF in a node.js server : I dont know i am really new to node.

Comment: Ok, I saw your code and that looks like a java program to me. How do you use it in JSF? Does "the enterprise" refuse to run JSF? Do they refuse to run java? If they can't/won't run java, then they can't use Jasper Reports. Then you have to rewrite it, I guess. If they can consider running java, but not JSF, then you could just execute your java program using [node child_process](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_processes.html) for instance.

Comment: JSF allow me to use java code on web so i can press button and it run it  Yes they refuse because JSF is another framework. But they can consider running java, so thanks for your advise and i look at this command

Comment: --I don't see how can i use child_process to run my .java

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. You can start / stop / control another process with Node.js - so You can start .java in another process and use it to generate PDF. But ... it may be not very efficient in terms of resource usage, so it's an open question.

Or, you can write a simple worker that will generate PDF from JSON data and use 0MQ or other inter-process communications between Node.js and this Java worker.

He-he, JSF was one of the worst technologies I ever saw (I believe it's still in the same state now as it was in 2007 when I left Java), even dumb JSP and servlets was better...